# how to add uibutton in tableviewcell when selected i,e in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios

Iam trying to add a button to uitableviewcell when selected but not able to figure out the best way. I need to add a button when i select the cell for the first time and remove the button when i select again

Comment: Why don't you add it in the first place and then make it visible/invisible on its selection.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a button like so.

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        // This will add a black button to the upper left corner       
        UITableViewCell * cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UIButton * button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        button.tag = IDENTIFIER;
        [cell addSubview:button];
    }
```

And than access it in other functions via [cell.contentView viewWithTag:IDENTIFIER]

Or just add the button inside Interface Builder and set the Hidden Property like so :

```
[button setHidden:YES];
```